# Twilio Chat: Error User not member of channel while joining a private channel

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am developing a 1:1 chat application. I use a PHP server to create the private channel before starting the application. The channels are created correctly.

The user tokens are genereated, chat client also created correctly. I see that the user is also created in the service.

When joining the private channel, it throws the error.

> code:50400 message:"User not member of channel" status:403

Javascript code:

```
    Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token,clientOptions).then(client => {
        chatClient = client;
        showMessage('Connecting.....');             
        chatClient.getChannelBySid(channelid)
        .then(function(chosenChannel) {
            showMessage('Joining Chat.....'); 
            myChannel=chosenChannel;                
            joinChannel();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
    });
```

It shows the message 'Connecting....' and then stops with the error.

PHP Code:

```
$client = new Client("sid", "token");       

$channel = $client->chat->services("serviceid")->channels
           ->create(array('friendlyName' => $friendlyName, 'uniqueName' => $uniqueName, 'type' => 'private'));
```

Comment: What goes on in the `joinChannel()` function?

Comment: myChannel.join() is called and subscribes to channel events like messageAdded, memberJoined etc.

Comment: I think chatClient.getChannelBySid(channelid) throws the error.

Comment: Is `myChannel` some sort of global then? Do you think it's `getChannelBySid` because your "Joining Chat...." message isn't shown?

Comment: myChannel is global. The debug log show like this. Twilsock D: send request: "host":"aim.twilio.com","path":"/v1/Instances/ISXXX1/Channels/CH0XX3","method":"GET".  Twilsock D: receive reply: body: {status: 403, message: "User not member of channel", code: 50400}

Comment: How are you creating the private room on the server?

Comment: Using PHP SDk. Post edited to include PHP channel creation code.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what's going on. Writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you create a private channel there's no way to define at that stage who is allowed to enter the channel. From [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/fundamentals#channels):

> Private Channels are not visible to Users that have not been invited or added to them. Private Channel Members can only be added by other Members with sufficient permissions, or via the REST API as controlled by your business logic.

So, in order for a user to join a private channel you need to either:

- [Add them to the channel using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/api/members?code-sample=code-add-a-member&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x)
- Invite the user to the channel from a [channel admin of the private channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/permissions)

Let me know if that makes sense at all

Comment: Thanks. Will check and confirm.